# Flutter make class from json array without key

Tags: flutter

this is simple part of response from my server:

```
"people_data": {
  "user": {
    "pk": "9917615035",
    "auto_expand_chaining": false,
    "highlight_reshare_disabled": false
  },
  "status": "ok"
},
"feeds": [
  {
    "taken_at": "1555388336",
    "pk": "00000"
  }
]
```

as you see `feeds` is an json array without key and i'm trying to make `feeds` class to handle this data but i can't do that

for example:

```
class PageInfo {
  PeopleData peopleData;
  Feeds feeds;
}

class Feeds {
  String taken_at;
  String pk;
}
```

`Feeds` class in here is not correct

Answer (score 0):

You have two options for this one:

1.Create a wrapper object that will receive the entire json you've posted here. Like this:

```
class Feed {
  final String takenAt;
  final String pk;

  Feed(this.takenAt, this.pk);

  factory Feed.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return Feed(json["taken_at"], json["pk"]);
  }
}

class FeedsList {
  final List<Feed> feeds;

  FeedsList(this.feeds);

  factory FeedsList.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return FeedsList(
        List.from(json["feeds"]).map((object) => Feed.fromJson(object)));
  }
}
```

2.Or in the place you're parsing the JSON do something like this:

```
List<Feed> list = List.from(json["feeds"]).map((object) => Feed.fromJson(object))
```